# How to calculate difference between current and previous row in Spark JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I parsed `.log` file to JavaRDD, after sorted this JavaRDD and now I have, for example `oldJavaRDD`:
`2016-03-28 | 11:00 | X | object1 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 11:01 | Y | object1 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 11:05 | X | object1 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 11:09 | X | object1 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 11:00 | X | object2 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 11:01 | Z | object2 | region1`

How I can get `newJavaRDD` for saving it to DB?
New JavaRDD structure have to be:
`2016-03-28 | 9 | object1 | region1`
`2016-03-28 | 1 | object2 | region1`
so, I have to calculate time between current and previous row (also use flag `X, Y, Z` in some cases to define, add time to result or not) and add new element to JavaRDD after changing `date, objectName` or `objectRegion`.

I can do it using this type of code (**map**), but I think it's not good and not the fastest way

```
    JavaRDD<NewObject> newJavaRDD = oldJavaRDD.map { r -> 
      String datePrev[] = ...
        if (datePrev != dateCurr ...) {
          return newJavaRdd;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you clarify what `X, Y, Z` mean? not clear on which records should be included in output and which shouldn't...

Comment: For example only: previous row contains flag `X`, current row contains `Y`, so we have transition `X->Y`. In this case we mustn't aggregate time between this rows, result `sum(11:01 - 11:00) = 0`. If `Y->X`, we have to aggregate time between rows, result `sum(11:05 - 11:01) = 4 minutes`. If `X->X` - aggregate too, result `4 minutes + sum(11:09 - 11:05) = 4 minutes + 4 minutes = 8 minutes`. I also have to realize few other rules, but all of them relates to difference between current and preview row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code example references `newJavaRDD` from within a transformation that *creates* `newJavaRDD` - that's impossible on a few different levels:

- You can't reference a variable on the right-hand-side of that variable's declaration...
- You can't use an RDD within a transformation on an RDD (same one or another one - that doesn't matter) - anything inside a transformation must be serialized by Spark, and Spark can't serialize its own RDDs (that would make no sense)

So, how should you do that?

**Assuming**:

1. Your intention here is to get a single record for each combination of `date` + `object` + `region`
2. There shouldn't be too many records for each such combination, so it's safe to `groupBy` these fields as key

You can `groupBy` the key fields, and then `mapValues` to get the "minute distnace" between first and last record (the function passed to `mapValues` can be changed to contain your exact logic if I didn't get it right). I'll use **Joda Time** library for the time calculations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // some setup code for this test:
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "test");

    // input:
    final JavaRDD<String[]> input = sc.parallelize(Lists.newArrayList(
            //              date        time     ?    object     region
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "X", "object1", "region1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "Y", "object1", "region1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:05", "X", "object1", "region1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:09", "X", "object1", "region1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:00", "X", "object2", "region1"},
            new String[]{"2016-03-28", "11:01", "Z", "object2", "region1"}
    ));

    // grouping by key:
    final JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String[]>> byObjectAndDate = input.groupBy(new Function<String[], String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(String[] record) throws Exception {
            return record[0] + record[3] + record[4]; // date, object, region
        }
    });

    // mapping each "value" (all record matching key) to result
    final JavaRDD<String[]> result = byObjectAndDate.mapValues(new Function<Iterable<String[]>, String[]>() {
        @Override
        public String[] call(Iterable<String[]> records) throws Exception {
            final Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();
            String[] previousRecord = iterator.next();
            int diffMinutes = 0;

            for (String[] record : records) {
                if (record[2].equals("X")) {  // if I got your intention right...
                    final LocalDateTime prev = getLocalDateTime(previousRecord);
                    final LocalDateTime curr = getLocalDateTime(record);
                    diffMinutes += Period.fieldDifference(prev, curr).toStandardMinutes().getMinutes();
                }
                previousRecord = record;
            }

            return new String[]{
                    previousRecord[0],
                    Integer.toString(diffMinutes),
                    previousRecord[3],
                    previousRecord[4]
            };
        }
    }).values();

    // do whatever with "result"...
}

// extracts a Joda LocalDateTime from a "record"
static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime(String[] record) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(record[0] + " " + record[1], formatter);
}

static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

P.S. In Scala this would take about 8 lines... :/

Comment: Sorry, that I confused you by pseudocode, you are right about `newJavaRDD`, I mean `return new NewObject(...)`. Never mind, your answer really helpful and working (fortunately, I can use java8 to reduce foolish lines).